# Check server side method being called

Tags: asp.net, validation

Can anyone tell me how to debug the code while running so that to see which server side method is being called?  There are Custom methods in the code which are converted to Dll and i want to find what is happening. Also the method called on Button click is not doing any validtion, but there is coupon validtion happening on button click. also there is no javascript for this, since i disabled javascript and run the code and the validations run fine.

The button declaration:

```
<asp:Button ID="Apply" runat="server onClick = "Apply_Click" .. >
```

The click event:

```
Apply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GetXML();
}
```

This just generates the XML but calls no other method. So now i have to find which server method is causing the server validation. Please can anyone help.

Comment: Put a break-point at `{`. Then debugger will stop there once the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have Visual Studio 2010 Pro (correct me if I'm wrong).  Once your page is running, go into Visual Studio, click the pause button, then the step-into button.  Now, when you click anything on the page (that sends the page server-side), VStudio will immediately kick-in, already paused.

You might also want to put break points on the blocks of code that you think are running.  Then you can check your stack trace to see what path was taken to get there.

There are also ways of setting break-points on variables (watch) so VStudio will break whenever that value has changed.  I think that feature is only available in Pro or Ultimate.